# Prove that if $E(X^n)$ exists then $E(X^i)$ exists for $i=1, ..., n-1$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

Let $X$ be  a discrete random variable and $n$ be a positive integer. Prove that if $E(X^n)$ exists then $E(X^i)$ exists for $i=1, ..., n-1$.

This seems like a simple enough question but I'm having trouble. Am I right in thinking that $E(X^n)=\sum x^np(x)$? If so I'm not too sure how to show this is true for $i \le n$

Comment: Just to be clear: exists means converges?

Comment: I believe so @Phicar. The way I worded it is how it was stated in the question. We haven't gone too deep into the theory on expected value. Just the basics of defining it, a couple small theorems, and computing it in problems.

Comment: Do you know Jensen's inequality?  That's by far the most common tool for proving this fact. Otherwise, you can also note that $\lvert x\rvert^i\leq\lvert x\rvert^n$ when $\lvert x\rvert\geq1$, and $\lvert x\rvert^i\leq1$ if $\lvert x\vert\leq 1$.

Comment: I have not heard of Jensen's inequality @NickPeterson, but I agree with your second statement, though I'm confused how to use it. I guess I'm not exactly sure what I am trying to show? Do I just want to show that $E(X^i) \lt \infty $?

Comment: what is $supp(X)$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Note that if $i\leq n$, then $\lvert x\rvert^i\leq \lvert x\rvert^n$ if $\lvert x\rvert\geq 1$, and $\lvert x\rvert^i\leq 1$ if $\lvert x\rvert<1$.

Therefore you can write
$$
\mathbb{E}[\lvert X\rvert^i]=\sum_{x\in\text{Supp}(X)}\lvert x\rvert^ip(x)\leq\sum_{\substack{x\in\text{Supp}(X)\\\lvert x\rvert\geq 1}}\lvert x\rvert^np(x)+\sum_{\substack{x\in\text{Supp}(x)\\\lvert x\rvert<1}}1\cdot p(x).
$$
Can you find ways to bound each of these above by quantities you know are finite?